# requests.get(): certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate, despite public certificate being used to verify

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, python-requests, wget

I am attempting to access some data from a website through python, but after my first attempt:

`requests.get('https://website.com')`

I was met with the following error:

`HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.website.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /file.php (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))`

I switched to a wget command to test (`wget website.com`), and ran into a similar error message:

`` ERROR: cannot verify cruzit.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G4,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,C=BE’: Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority. To connect to cruzit.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'. ``

After doing some research, I found that my issue could be solved by simply including the public SSL certificate that the site was using. I went to the site in my web browser and downloaded the public certificate. After testing it out with wget once again (`wget --ca-certificate=certificate.crt https://website.com`), the command was successful.

I implemented this change in my code:

`requests.get('https://website.com', verify='/path/to/cert')`

Despite the changes, I was getting the same error.

Note: I did use `verify=False` and `--no-check-certificate` for `requests.get()` and `wget` respectively, which did work. I do not want to implement this, as it is not secure.

Comment: It will not work with trusting the server certificate explicitly since the server certificate is not a CA certificate, but `verify` expects CA certificates. You need to trust the root CA and any missing chain certificates instead. The reason trusting the certificate directly works with curl is because it implements X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN option for verification, while python does not.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich+ in particular [that server supplies the _wrong_ chain cert](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=cruzit.com) namely AlphaSSL SHA256 G2 instead of G4 (and it's expired to boot). You need to give (python and OpenSSL) http://secure.globalsign.com/cacert/alphasslcasha256g4.crt (from AIA) converted to PEM, also available at https://ssl-tools.net/subjects/8f7702dc0e21d05e555fa7c877ee1ae931ead382 (I usually give crt.sh but it seems to be down?!), plus the GlobalSign root (which should be in all your usual truststores)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, I downloaded the given crt file and then converted it to PEM with "openssl x509 -in cert.crt -out cert.pem -outform PEM". The error persists. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Did you put that chain cert PLUS the GlobalSign root cert (both in PEM) in the `verify=` file, as @Steffen said and I made more specific?